# How to load a JMeter parameter using a JDBC query

Tags: database, performance, testing, jmeter, jmeter-3.2

I'm trying to fetch the last **id** value of the database using the select query in JDBC request and I need to pass the  id as the starting value for the counter.
I tried adding the variable in the counter as ${variable} / ${variable_1} but nothing worked for me.

[image: here I'm fetching the entity_id in "status" variable]

[here i need to pass the value of that variable to starting value of counter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ecfl.png)

How can i achieve the same?

I have tried adding ${status}, ${status_1} but both didn't work for me

Comment: your 2 images are identical. Pls re-up the image showing that you did fetching `id` from JDBC request

Answer (score 1):

According to [JDBC Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) sampler documentation

> If the Variable Names list is provided, then for each row returned by a Select statement, the variables are set up with the value of the corresponding column (if a variable name is provided), and the count of rows is also set up. For example, if the Select statement returns 2 rows of 3 columns, and the variable list is `A,,C`, then the following variables will be set up:
>
> ```
> A_#=2 (number of rows)
> A_1=column 1, row 1
> A_2=column 1, row 2
> C_#=2 (number of rows)
> C_1=column 3, row 1
> C_2=column 3, row 2
> ```

So if your JDBC PreProcessor runs successfully you should have the following variables set up:

- `${status_#}` with the value of `1`
- `${status_1}` with the return value of your SQL query

The [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) which are pre-defined and created can be visualized using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debug-jmeter).

---

**My expectation is that your SQL statement fails somewhere somehow, i.e. you need to remove the semicolon `;` from it.**

Comment: I tried removing but didn't reflect anything. also I feel my preprocessor query is executing properly because in the debug sampler I could able to see the proper value from the query.